# Swagger Param Documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

**Current State:**

I have two methods in my controller to get data based on what parameters are passed.  The code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/samples")
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = {"cost"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSamplesByIdAndCost(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam(value = "cost") String cost) {
        return "result";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = {"cost", "size"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSamplesByIdCostAndSize(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam(value = "cost") String cost,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "size") String size) {
    return "ID : " + id + " / COST : " + cost + " / SIZE : " + size;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the swagger documentation is not what I expected.

[image]

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to remove {?size,cost} from the Request URL?

Here is my Docket info:

```
@Bean
    public Docket myApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class,
                        String.class)
                .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .alternateTypeRules(
                        newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                                typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                                typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                        newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                                .code(500)
                                .message("500 message")
                                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error"))
                                .build()))
                .enableUrlTemplating(true);

    }

    @Autowired
    TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return new UiConfiguration(
                "validatorUrl",// url
                "none",       // docExpansion          => none | list
                "alpha",      // apiSorter             => alpha
                "schema",     // defaultModelRendering => schema
                UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS,
                false,        // enableJsonEditor      => true | false
                true);        // showRequestHeaders    => true | false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Tobias Raski's answer to understand more about why this problem exists.

There is a work around for this.  You can see some details here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1484

In summary there is an experimental UI that fixes the issue.  This may eventually be irrelevant when a future fix comes out.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple documentations for the same path based on query strings is not something that is supported by Swagger spec and therefore not by swagger-ui.

What you have enabled by setting `enableUrlTemplating(true)` appears to be an incubation feature in springfox but won't work as of now with swagger-ui.

Relevant discussion can be found here:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1665
- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/866

For now it seem like you either have to live with paths looking weird in the swagger-ui, or you have to merge your documentation.

Comment: You are correct.  I have added my own answer that is more of a work around.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1874):

> Swagger spec does not allow multiple endpoints that differ by request params. However you could use the experimental feature to get around it using `docket#enableUrlTemplates(true)`. Keep in mind it is experimental. Also please upgrade to 2.7.0

Comment: No - the link is supplementary. The quote is the answer. The answer is basically that it's not allowed, which is fine as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'params' attribute in your @RequestMapping annotation, your code will still work.

Comment: That would break the controller. the two methods would have identical mapping.  The only thing distinguishing those two are the params part of the @RequestMapping

Comment: How about removing getSamplesByIdAndCost and making the Size Requestparam optional (required=false) then?

Comment: The main purpose of separating them is that the documentation for each of them is very unique.

Answer (score 0):

you can change maven pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui-rfc6570</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

use `springfox-swagger-ui-rfc6570` instead of `springfox-swagger-ui`

Click [here](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-rfc6570-support-strong-incubating-strong) to see more.